# How can I (or can I?) create a Windows 8 app that will run on both tablets and laptops/desktops?

Tags: deployment, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

In *Debug | Configuration Manager...*, I've got *Active solution configuration* set to **Debug** and *Active solution platform* set to **x86**, and I've got *Project contexts* set to:

My project, Debug, ARM, with both the Build and Deploy checkboxes checked.

Does this mean my app will only run on ARM devices? If so, can I make this project "cross-device" or will I need two separate but virtually identical projects?

### UPDATE

That doesn't work so well (setting to "ARM" in Project contexts), because in the designer I then get, "Design view is unavailable for x64 and ARM target platforms."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you app is going to run on all 3 platforms (if you select "Any CPU" in the Active solution platform)
When you create the app package to upload to the store (Project->Store->Create App Package), you can choose the platform individually. Which you would need to if you are using Bing Maps (you gotta compile for each platform individually)

Answer (score 1):

It will run on ARM and **might** run on other devices that have compatible architecture. You don't need 2 identical projects, you can have 2 different configurations and have 2 (or whatever number you want) builds - one for ARM and one for x86, for example.

Comment: How to have the two different configurations? I right-clicked in the grid (which seems to accept multiple configurations) but it presented no context menu.

Comment: Build->Configuration Manager->Active Solution Platform->New - this will create a new configuration. Customize it per your needs.

Comment: Okay; it seems kind of strange that, rather than adding a second configuration in the list, it adds a second to the comboBox.